# How to find out if an IList object contains a specific value anywhere in the list

Tags: c#, list, razor

This code obviously doesn't work...but it's what I want to accomplish (Using IList)

```
if (this.Model.myOptionsList.Contains(SelectedOption.value)){

     do something
}
```

The contents of myOptionsList looks like this:

[image]

SelectedOption.value contains an Id...i.e. 34
I need to know if that exists in the myOptionsList.

The catch is that I need to do that on the Razor page because it won't be available in the controller.

Comment: You can use Any method like this : this.Model.myOptionsList.Any(x=>x.Id==SelectedOption.value)

Comment: Thanks, I'm using IList which doesn't have an .Any property. It has .Contains. If it translates easily, I might be able to change the type...but It could end up being extremely painful to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many methods, two friends said. I say three other methods(Count, Exists, FirstOrDefault).

Exists(it is better):

```
if (this.Model.myOptionsList.Exists(d => d.Id == SelectedOption.value))
{
    // do something
 }
```

Count:

```
  if (this.Model.myOptionsList.Count(d => d.Id == SelectedOption.value) > 0)
  {
                // do something
  }
```

FirstOrDefault:

```
 if (this.Model.myOptionsList.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Id == SelectedOption.value) != null)
  {
                // do something
  }
```

also you can write if in two ways.
The first method, if the condition is false, return;
Next go to second part( // do something)
way 1:

```
if (this.Model.myOptionsList.Count(d => d.Id == SelectedOption.value) == 0) return;

     //other
     // do something
```

way 2:

```
if (this.Model.myOptionsList.Count(d => d.Id == SelectedOption.value) == 0)
 {
    // do something
 }
```

Comment: Thank you!  That's a lot of options!

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you can leverage LINQ's [`Any`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=net-8.0) (assuming types match, otherwise you will need to parse the selected value):

```cs
if (this.Model.myOptionsList.Any(o => o.Id == SelectedOption.value)){
     // do something
}
```

I would recommend to go over [LINQ samples](https://github.com/dotnet/try-samples/blob/main/101-linq-samples/index.md) or some book like "LINQ Pocket Reference" by Albahari.

Comment: Thanks, I'm using IList which doesn't have an .Any property.  It has .Contains.  If it translates easily, I might be able to change the type...but It could end up being extremely painful to do that.

Comment: @jpolo `Any` is not a property, it is extension method from LINQ. try adding `using System.Linq` (or `@using System.Linq` in case of Razor)  to the file.

Comment: Added this to the top of the view @using System.Linq ... .Any is still not available and the "using System.Linq" is greyed out with a message that says "using directive is not necessary."

Comment: @jpolo what is the actual type of `myOptionsList`?

Comment: System.Collections.IList

Comment: @jpolo And what underlying items does it store. I would recommend to change type to something `IList<MyOption>`

Answer (score 1):

Using .Select it should be possible

```
if (this.Model.myOptionsList.Select(i => i.Id).Contains(SelectedOption.value)){
  do something
}
```

Comment: .Select is not an available property....